# How can I repeat a specific data in each facet of facet_grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2

the first column of my dataset is Date/Time and the 5 other columns contain measurements from 5 sensors. I would like to display the results using face_grid.
Facet 1 would include 2 curves : sensor 2 and sensor 1
Facet 2 would include 2 curves : sensor 3 and sensor 1
Facet 3 would include 2 curves : sensor 4 and sensor 1
Facet 4 would include 2 curves : sensor 5 and sensor 1

I don't know how to add that same sensor 1 data to each facet of the facet_grid. Would anyone know how to do that? Should I use Pivot_longer? if so, I am still blocked after this step.

(the solution I am looking for must enable me to show the 5 colors of the curves in the legend).

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly different approach than the one by @r2evans. First, reshaping to  long is definitely the first step. Afterwards create a facetted plot where you drop the category you want to show in all facets. The latter could then be added via a second `geom_line` (or `geom_point`or ...) layer for which you use only the data for sensor 1 where as the important step we have to rename or drop the column you facet by. This way this layer will show up in all facets.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(
  Date = 1:10
)
dat[paste0("sensor", 1:5)] <- lapply(1:5, \(x) runif(10))

dat_long <- dat |>
  pivot_longer(-Date, names_to = "sensor")

ggplot(
  filter(dat_long, sensor != "sensor1"),
  aes(Date, value, color = sensor)
) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(
    data = filter(dat_long, sensor == "sensor1") |>
      rename(sensor1 = sensor),
    aes(color = sensor1)
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~sensor)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to Stefan, r2evans and Jon Spring for your answers ! The Stefan's one is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'll facet `mtcars` on `cyl`, repeating `cyl==8` in all three facets.

What we need to do is:

- duplicate `cyl` so that we can use one for coloring and one for faceting
- copy `cyl == 8` into the other groups, rewriting one of the `cyl`-columns to the target  `cyl` group (in a cartesian join with the other `cyl`s)
- plot, faceting as usually, but using one `cyl` for colors, the other for faceting

```r
mt <- transform(mtcars, cyl_facet = cyl)
mt2 <- subset(mt, cyl_facet == 8, select = -cyl_facet) |> 
  # cartesian/outer join
  merge(data.frame(cyl_facet = c(4, 6)), by = c()) |> 
  rbind(mt)
ggplot(mt2, aes(disp, mpg, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(cyl_facet ~ .)
```

[image: ggplot with cyl 8 in all three facets]

Answer (score 1):

As a variation of `r2evans`'s approach, we can use one layer that uses data without the facet variable (that data will appear on all facets), and one layer that does the facet variable -- that data will only appear on the respective facet.

```
mtall <- transform(mtcars, cyl_facet = cyl)
mt8 <- subset(mtcars, cyl == 8)
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(disp, mpg, color = factor(cyl)), data = mt8) +
  geom_point(aes(disp, mpg, color = factor(cyl)), data = mtall) +
  facet_wrap(cyl_facet ~ .)
```

[image]